# screen dimming automatically when switch activity

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm working on an application to record wounds with the camera2-api. For this I scan a qr-code with the patient data and then start to take  picture of the wound. But when the activity (to take pictures) launches it seems like the screen gtes dimmed till I touch the screen and I dont know why

I think its up to the device because I use the same fragment for scanning and to take pictures and when I launch the ScanActivity the issue dosn't accure

**What I have already tried**

Change the display options of the device (brightness of the
screen adjust automatically to your environment).

Change the power saving mode activation time to 30 minutes

Set the AE state like this

```
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
```

and

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

**My questions**

I'm not sure if the screen gets darker because of the exposure of the camera, the brightness of the screen or maybe the device switch to the 
power saving mode.

How can i prevent that?

Comment: Automatic screen brightness can be turned off and power saving mode activation time adjusted in the device settings assuming it's a regular Android phone or tablet.

Comment: yes but thats not the problem. i got the same issue when i turn off the automatic screen brightness or when i set  power saving mode activation time to 30 min

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution. There was a AlertDialog without a view. At the begin i show the user the number of pictures but if the number is 0 no view added to the alert and that looks like the screen is dimming

Answer (score 0):

main issue in inactivity - be notified about user's gestures(touches, clicks etc)
for this you need to override method dispatchTouchEvent in your activity class

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    ev?.let { event ->
        if (event.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
            touchChannel.tryEmit(Touch())
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

now you are notified about every touch(you even can filter events)
add new property and getter to your activity

```
private val touchChannel: MutableSharedFlow<Touch> = MutableSharedFlow<Touch>(extraBufferCapacity = 1)

override fun getGestureChannel(): SharedFlow<Touch> = touchChannel
```

and now you can subscribe in any fragment if you need

```
(requireActivity() as GestureHandler).getGestureChannel()
        .onEach { touch ->
            //
        }
        .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)



 interface GestureHandler {
    fun getGestureChannel(): SharedFlow<Touch>
 }
```